# string substitution from text file to another string

Tags: sql, string, bash, awk, sed

I have a text file with three columns of text (strings) per line.  I want to create an SQL insert command by substituting each of the three strings into a skeleton SQL command.  I have put place markers in the skeleton script and used SED s/placemarker1/first string/ but with no success. Is there an easier way to accomplish this task.  I used pipes to repeat the process for 'second string' etc.  I actually used awk to get the fields but could not convert to the actual values.

```
enter code here
    for i in [ *x100* ]; do
    if [ -f "$i" ]; then {
        grep -e "You received a payment" -e "Transaction ID:" -e "Receipt No: " $i  >> ../temp
        cat ../temp | awk 'NR == 1 {printf("%s\t",$9)} NR == 2 {printf("%s\t",$9)}  NR == 3 {printf("%s\n",$3)}' | awk '{print $2,$1,$3}' | sed 's/(/ /' | sed 's/)./ /' >> ../temp1
        cat temp1 | awk 'email="$1"; transaction="$2"; ccreceipt="$3";'
        cat /home/linux014/opt/skeleton.sql | sed 's/EMAIL/"$email"/' | sed 's/TRANSACTION/"$transaction"/' | sed 's/CCRECEIPT/"$ccreceipt"/' > /home/linux014/opt/new-member.sql
        rm -f ../temp
    } fi
    done
```

I cannot figure out how to get the values instead of the names of the variables inserted into my string.

Sample input (one line only):

```
catdog@gmail.com 2w4e5r6t7y8u9i8u7 1111-2222-3333-4444
```

Sample actual output:

```
INSERT INTO users (email,paypal_tran,CCReceipt) VALUES ('"$email"','"$transaction"','"$ccreceipt"');
```

Preferred output:

```
INSERT INTO users (email,paypal_tran,CCReceipt) VALUES ('catdog@gmail.com','2w4e5r6t7y8u9i8u7','1111-2222-3333-4444');
```

Comment: sample input and expected output would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{print "INSERT INTO users (email,paypal_tran,CCReceipt) VALUES"; print "(\x27"$1"\x27,\x27"$2"\x27,\x27"$3"\x27);"}' input.txt
```

Converts your sample input to preferred output. It should work for multi line input.

**EDIT**

The variables you are using in this line:

```
cat temp1 | awk 'email="$1"; transaction="$2"; ccreceipt="$3";'
```

are only visible to awk and in this command. They are not shell variables.
Also in your `sed` commands remove those single quotes then you can get the values:

```
sed "s/EMAIL/$email/"
```

Comment: I am trying this approach but I still get the $email and not its value catdog@gmail.com.  I cannot seem to get the values but the names of the input.  My assignment must be wrong.

Comment: This works if you have a file which its content is like the one that you posted as sample input

Comment: Thank you.  This seems to have resolved my problem.  I appreciate the effort and code!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `bash`,

```
while read email transaction ccreceipt; do echo "INSERT INTO users (email,paypal_tran,CCReceipt) VALUES ('$email','$transaction','$ccreceipt');"; done<inputfile
```

inputfile:

```
catdog@gmail.com 2w4e5r6t7y8u9i8u7 1111-2222-3333-4444
dog@gmail.com 2dsdsda53563u9i8u7 3333-4444-5555-6666
```

**Test:**

```
sat:~$ while read email transaction ccreceipt; do echo "INSERT INTO users (email,paypal_tran,CCReceipt) VALUES ('$email','$transaction','$ccreceipt')"; done<inputfile
INSERT INTO users (email,paypal_tran,CCReceipt) VALUES ('catdog@gmail.com','2w4e5r6t7y8u9i8u7','1111-2222-3333-4444')
INSERT INTO users (email,paypal_tran,CCReceipt) VALUES ('dog@gmail.com','2dsdsda53563u9i8u7','3333-4444-5555-6666')
```

Comment: @user3386373 : don't forget to vote on answers that you find useful even if it's not those who fix the issue at first ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can write a small procedure for this

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[appInsert]--
@string VARCHAR(500)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @I INT  
DECLARE @SubString VARCHAR(500)
SET @String = 'catdog@gmail.com 2w4e5r6t7y8u9i8u7 1111-2222-3333-4444'
SET @I = 1  
SET @String = REPLACE(@String, ' ', '`~`')

    WHILE @I > 0
        BEGIN
        SET @SubString = SUBSTRING (REVERSE(@String), 1, ( CHARINDEX( '`~`', REVERSE(@String)) - 1))
        SET @String = SUBSTRING(@String, 1, LEN(@String) - CHARINDEX( '`~`', REVERSE(@String)) - 2 )
        print REVERSE(@SubString) + ' === ' + @String
        SET @i = CHARINDEX( '`~`', @String)
        END

END
```